# Configure Autofac Container for background thread

Tags: asp.net, backgroundworker, autofac

I have an asp.net MVC site which has many components registered using an InstancePerHttpRequest scope, however I also have a "background task" which will run every few hours which will not have an httpcontext.

I would like to get an instance of my IRepository which has been registered like this

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(EfRepository<>)).As(typeof(IRepository<>))
     .InstancePerHttpRequest();
```

How do I do this from a non http context using Autofac? I think the IRepository should use the  InstancePerLifetimeScope

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/27903481/389424

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several ways of how you can do that:

1. The best one in my opinion. You can register the repository as InstancePerLifetimeScope as you said. It works with HttpRequests and LifetimeScopes equally well.

   ```
   builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(EfRepository<>)).As(typeof(IRepository<>))
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
   ```
2. Your registration for HttpRequest may differ from registration for LifetimeScope, then you can have two separate registrations:

   ```
   builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(EfRepository<>)).As(typeof(IRepository<>))
       .WithParameter(...)
       .InstancePerHttpRequest(); // will be resolved per HttpRequest

   builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(EfRepository<>)).As(typeof(IRepository<>))
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope(); // will be resolved per LifetimeScope
   ```
3. You can explicitly create `"HttpRequest"` scope using its tag. Exposed through `MatchingScopeLifetimeTags.RequestLifetimeScopeTag` property in new versions.

   ```
   using (var httpRequestScope = container.BeginLifetimeScope("httpRequest")) // or "AutofacWebRequest" for MVC4/5 integrations
   {
       var repository = httpRequestScope.Resolve<IRepository<Entity>>();
   }
   ```

Comment: I did option 3 like this: _container.BeginLifetimeScope("AutofacWebRequest")

Comment: @Paul Thanks. Request tag was changed to "AutofacWebRequest" and exposed through MatchingScopeLifetimeTags.RequestLifetimeScopeTag in new versions. Updated the answer.

Comment: #1 works well. To get container you can do the following: `var container = AutofacDependencyResolver.Current.ApplicationContainer;`